# Could CouchDB CORS "origins" serve to restrict read access?

Tags: couchdb, cors

I had thought: Could CouchDB CORS origins, set to the domain of the web server, serve to restrict users from accessing (reading) attachments (images) by simply entering the url in their browser?

So if you have images in your Couch, I enter the image url i.e....

http://couch.somewebdomain.com:5984/yourdatabase/thedocid/privateimage.jpg

I can see the image in the browser. What would be the "origin" of my request? It wouldn't be the web app server right? So blocked?

Does this make sense?

EDIT: I had a thought...

I could code an http proxy in PHP or perhaps node.js to run on the server. Pass all Couch http through that. Put the authorization code in that proxy and setup Couch CORS origin to only allow http from the proxy.

Could someone who knows Couch really well offer some advice?

Answer (score 0):

CORS will apply only when you make requests from a domain other than the domain of the CouchDB server. For example, consider an AJAX request from `http://mydomain.com/index.html`(via javascript) to `http://yourcouch:5984/db/...etc`, in this scenario CORS will apply.

If you're trying to restrict access by user, I suggest you set the `local.ini` variable `[couch_httpd_auth] require_valid_user` to `true`. That way, any request must be made with a valid credential (that is, an authenticated user).